# GDB - modifying a C string

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I got some assembler code that creates a formatted string using `sprintf()`:

```
...
0x00304272: call   0x557b2 <dyld_stub___sprintf_chk>
...
```

I'm trying to find out how the exactly the string is formatted, so I found the format argument `"%s%s"`, which is stored in the `$ecx` register. Now, I don't know where one string ends and the next one begins, so I'd like to alter the format argument to be `"%s@%s"`.

I have tried to use `set $ecx = "%s@%s"` (which seems to work, according to `print (char *) $ecx`), but for some reason, `sprintf()` uses the *old* format string instead of the new one.

Did I miss anything? How do I modify the format string?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be editing the stack instead?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: You're right! How do I do that though (sorry, I'm still new to GDB)? I've tried `set ($esp + 0xC) = "%s@%s"`, but it tells me `Left operand of assignment is not an lvalue`.

Comment: Since your new string is longer than the original string, it will not be safe for you to overwrite the memory on the stack because you'll corrupt whatever comes next.  Also, the string "%s%s" won't actually be on the stack, just a pointer to it will be on the stack.  Anyway, you still have the corruption problem wherever it resides.

Comment: @TJD: Is there no way to allocate the new string on the heap and just overwrite the pointer on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to use set $ecx = "%s@%s"

If you are in 32-bit mode (I assume you are, since you've used `ecx` and not `rcx`), by the time you are stopped on the `call ...sprintf`, the parameter to `sprintf` has already been pused onto the stack.

*If* the parameter came from `%ecx`, you need to re-assign new value to `%ecx` *before* that value is pushed onto the stack.